# How to print message in terminal with concat two strings in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I knows print() will useful but how to merge or concat two string variables.
like print(" "+str1+" "+str2)

Comment: Your code should work but Arnolds way is the pregerred one in Dart.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is more of a dart question.
You can achieve that using:

```
print('Something $string1 something more ${someObject.string2} even more $string3');
```

Answer (score 34):

In dart there are many string options.

For concatenation, you can do :

- `'hello $myVariable'`
- `"hello ${myVariable.myProperty}"`
- `'hello ' 'world'` (only works with string literals)
- `'hello' + myVariable`

So in your case, you can do a `print(" $str1 $str2")`

Use $var instead of ${var} here